# I can't find an add-on I installed

Tags: add-on

on called "rigify_animbox". but I can't find on my add-on.[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the addon's documentation for installation?

Comment: @L0Lock I guess not, what is that?

Comment: Wherever/whoever you got the addon from, there's usually instructions on how to install that specific addon, or where to download it. Most of the time you just download a .py or a .zip file and click the `Install` button in Blender, but it can be different sometimes. Hence, make sure you downloaded the right file and followed the right installation process as the addon's developer intended.